# System.Windows.Forms.Panel.VisibleChanged event raised when opening designer (project is NOT running)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

My system is running Windows 10 64-bit.  I'm using Visual Studio 16.0.30320.27 D16.6.

I am extending a project where I cannot change the code, but I can inherit the form to override its functionality.

My problem is when I attempt to open any windows form designer file, it gives me an error that occurs in the function *BodyPanel_VisibleChanged*.  The error occurs because the project isn't actually running, and the function is attempting to grab an object that is only initialized at run time.

**So here are my questions:** why is the *VisibleChanged* event being fired if the project isn't even running?  Is there a way for me to change this behavior?  Was this behavior different in prior Visual Studio versions (this didn't happen in version 2013)?

UPDATE1:
I've overrided the function to not call the base function when in design mode, but still getting the same error after rebuilding:

```
Protected Overrides Sub BodyPanel_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles pnlCriteria_Item.VisibleChanged,
            pnlCriteria_Main.VisibleChanged,
            pnlCriteria.VisibleChanged,
            pnlPlannedWorkOrders.VisibleChanged

        If Not DesignMode Then
            MyBase.BodyPanel_VisibleChanged(sender, e)
        End If
    End Sub
```

UPDATE2: I also overrided OnVisibleChanged, but the error is still happening.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnVisibleChanged(e As EventArgs)
        If Not DesignMode Then
            MyBase.OnVisibleChanged(e)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you override `OnVisibleChanged` and call `base.OnVisibleChanged(e)` only when `DesignMode` is false? Btw, accessing objects in that event handler without checking for null is not a good thing.

Comment: I was not aware of DesignMode, that is useful to know, thank you.  However, after doing as you suggest and rebuilding, I still get the same error.  I'll update the base question shortly.

Comment: To respond to your other statement, the code that is failing wasn't written by me, and I don't have access to change it.

Comment: It is not clear from the description, but for the implemented override to work, it needs to be the code that the designer is running.  By this I mean that you will need to add a inherited form that inherits from the modified base form.  That way you are designing a form based on the modified original.

Comment: You're not overriding **OnVisibleChanged**. That's a method that has one parameter, it's not an event handler, it's the method that raises the event (or it does not). It should be `protected overrides sub OnVisibleChanged(e as eventargs)`

Comment: You need to change the code in the original project, or you can redesign your form instead of inheriting the original project.